# Launching a very complex command in a Python program

Tags: python, shell, command-line, subprocess, popen

Inside a Python program I need to launch a complex command, indeed a python program that needs lots of arguments. What I need to launch is something like this:

```
./calculations.py -id -k "{'names':['r','pst'],'index_IN':['at','gl'],'index_OUT':[1,1]}"

                      -r "[False,False]" -N "[False,False]" -c "['values1**2','np.exp(values2)']"

                       $SCRATCH/my_dir/*
```

(Indeed, it's even more complex, but the main ideas are in this example).

So, the key points are the presence of both `"` and `'` in the example, and the use of calculation (square numbers and exponentiation with `numpy`). I have tried `subprocess.Popen` but somehow I can't get it to work. My attempt:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["./calculations.py -id", "-k", 

       "{'names':['r','pst'],'index_IN':['at','gl'],'index_OUT':[1,1]}"], ........])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Calling another Python program as a subprocess is often misdirected. Can't you `import calculations` and call its main function directly as a native Python function call?

Comment: Do you need to run the process in the background or just run it? Do you need to see its output or its exit status?

Comment: Do the calculations need to be passed exactly as shown, i.e. the literal strings `'values1**2'` and `'np.exp(values2)'`, or are they supposed to be replaced with the results of first evaluating those Python expressions? I suspect it is the former (strings) because `values1` and `values2` are undefined variables.

Comment: Passing in what look like Python executable expressions as command-line arguments also looks like the real problem is that `calculations.py` is evil. Like, Cthulhu evil.

Comment: @tripleee: I doubt your comment makes much sense to many of the folks hear reading it, especially the "Cthulhu" reference.

Comment: @martineau yes, the parameters need to be expressed in exactly that way. Program "calculations" is a very sophisticated program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save strings as raw string in python with the r prefix, if you need both ' and " than consider using a raw long python string:

```
cmdAttributes = r"""{'names':['r','pst'],'index_IN':['at','gl'],'index_OUT':[1,1]}"""
```

So same thing with flexible entries:

```
pnames = r"['r','pst']"
pindex_IN = r"['at','gl']"
pindex_OUT = r"[1,1]"

cmdAttributes = r"""{{'names':{Names},'index_IN':{Index_IN},'index_OUT':{Index_OUT} }}""".format(
        Names = pnames,
        Index_IN = pindex_IN,
        Index_OUT = pindex_OUT)
```

cmdAttributes will be the same for both codes.

Comment: It seems a good idea, but why 3 `"` instead of 2 (one needed for the command and one for the string)?

Comment: Ah no thats a intern python type called long string which starts and ends with 3 " It is also used to comment on functions and classes. But since it does not use " and ' for anything I always use this data type to save command line arguments.

Comment: One more, imagine I need to add not only constants but also a variable (because I have to launch many times this command inside a loop), so `'index_OUT'` needs to be a vector not always [1, 1], but in general [my_num, my_num]. Because `format` with `{} {}` does not seem to work. Thx.

Comment: The `r` prefix is not needed, just the triple quotes, An `r` prefix suppresses the normal special interpretation of escape sequences (those starting with a backslash (`\\`) character). This is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in the documentation.

Comment: It's also better to make the first argument passed to `Popen` (`args`) a sequence of strings instead of a single, typically very long, string because the former is platform dependent—as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) in the documentation for `Popen`.

Comment: This seems to be quite close to the solution, although it is still not wotking. I don't know if the problem is perhaps in when performing the square and the exponential... OK, anyway, thanks

Comment: For the { to work with format just double the one that are "real" like I did in my example. I tested the code, stop telling me it does not work xD
@martineau is right, best would be to pass it as a List of Strings instead of one long one

Comment: Ok, now it's working (I deleted a previous comment that was useless). Thank you very much!